# DIV floats unexpectedly in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, mootools

I'm using mootools slider and somehow the DIV tag floats next to the parent div in Chrome.  This didn't happen in other browsers.  I'm managed to find a workaround by adding an empty div with a fixed height but looking for a better way of handling this without changing the DOM structure.  Is there a solution to this in CSS?  Why the unexpected floating occurs only in Chrome?

Case 1: div.lowerPanel does not appear and floats upper left

http://jsfiddle.net/superkingjo1/bQpjV/

Case 2: Added empty DIV with fixed height puts div.lowerPanel in expected position
http://jsfiddle.net/superkingjo1/bQpjV/4/

thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2):

Could it be this line (3rd line in the html)

```
<div class="mainPanelLayersDiv" style="position: relative; float: left; ">
```

I removed the `float: left;` from this in the first fiddle and got what appeared to be the same result as fiddle #2.

Comment: Oh that's right.  Why didn't I think of that..  Thank you so much for your help!